# How do I remove firebase warning and console message regarding Firebase/Analytics and swizzing respectively?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Wonder why firebase throws a warning saying that I've not included `Firebase/Analytics` while I don't need it. I'm using `Firebase/Messaging` though. And I know messaging is working as intended. So, how would I remove the warning that says:

> <MyProjectPath>/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources/Firebase.h:75:10: "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add `Firebase/Analytics` to your Podfile or add FirebaseAnalytics.framework to your project to ensure Firebase Messaging works as intended."

[image: Xcode warning]

1. I do not wish to add `FirebaseAnalytics` to my project.
2. I do not wish to edit the pod.

Also, every time I run my project the console keeps showing me a message regarding `method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging`.

[image: console screenshot]

1. I do not wish to change the existing push-notification implementation to manual.
2. I do not wish to set `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` to `NO` (it gives me other info that I need).

Comment: Guys let me know if you need the code snippets associated with `Firebase/Messaging` implementation. Although I think it's necessary in this situation. Not sure.

Answer (score 8):

Disable the warning by defining the preprocessor define `FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_SUPPRESS_WARNING` in the build:

[image]

Messaging works fine without Analytics, but provides [additional features](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) when Analytics is added.

The log message is a notice and you can adjust the level of Firebase messages that print to the console with `setLoggerLevel`. See details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasecore/api/reference/Classes/FirebaseConfiguration#/c:objc(cs)FIRConfiguration(im)setLoggerLevel:).

Comment: Thanks. Adding `FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_SUPPRESS_WARNING=1` to `Preprocessor Macros` removed the warning. Yes, I know adding analytics gives additional features, but it's not required at the moment.

Comment: Although setting the logger level to `min` didn't remove the console warning message. `FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.min)`

Comment: That's weird. It would probably be easiest to use the Xcode debugger to see why the log level adjustment isn't working.

Comment: Log level adjustments are working fine. Setting log level to max does increase the number of verbose log messages. I even tried `FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(FirebaseLoggerLevel(rawValue: 2)!)` and it does produce a `NSAssert` crash. Maybe this particular message has the highest priority log level, which is weird.

Comment: I tried the above, but get: 


warning: 'FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_SUPPRESS_WARNING' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]. Any tips?

Comment: FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_SUPPRESS_WARNING does not exist in recent Firebase versions, so alternatively, you could `pod update` instead.